# Scale DOM on page load

Tags: jquery, animation, scale, onload

I want to have the div element scaled when the page is loaded. From what I've searched this is correct or almost correct syntax using jQuery; but when I load the page nothing happens. This is surely a simple fix I just am too new at this to spot it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link href="twitter-bootstrap-v2/docs/assets/css/example-fixed-layout.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>


    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
     $("body").onload(function() {
     $('#div1').effect('scale'{percent:200},1000)
     });
    </script>

<div id="div1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this syntax (remember to include jQuery AND jQueryUI):

```
$(function () {
    $('#div1').effect('scale', {
        percent: 200
    }, 1000)
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eC23T/)**

(note that `$(function () {` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() {`)

Comment: Ok this worked thank you! What effect/animation would you use to say stretch a div horizontally? not just zoom.

Comment: I'd start by animating the width.

Answer (score 1):

Effect will not stick at the end. I recommend you animate the zoom css property:

```
$(function () {
     $('#div1').animate({
         'zoom':2
    }, 500)
});
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/eC23T/1/